# How to hide the menu icon when back button is shown?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a side menu with:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true">
```

So it is accesable from each view of my app. So now when there is a back view i have a back icon AND the menu icon in the top left nav-bar. How can i disable the menu-icon when there is a back-icon?

The method from [here](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/show-side-menu-or-back-button-conditionally/16107):

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function (e, data) {
    if (data.enableBack) {
        $scope.$root.showMenuIcon = false;
    } else {
        $scope.$root.showMenuIcon = true;
    }
});
```

Is not working! Because it is never called! Maybe `$ionicView.beforeEnter` does not exist anymore? At least it is never fired.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem with this code in each view controller

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
});
$scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function () {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(true);
});
```

Hope it helps

don't forget to add `$ionicSideMenuDelegate` to your controller

Comment: Wouldnt this disable the menu? I want to have the menu on each view like i have it now but i just dont want to show the menu icon when a back icon is shown.